# how to redirect php page with parameters into new tab or window

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have print option in my application. When user click on print button the print page should be open in another tab/window.

Again I am sending some parameters with print page as it contain dynamic values.

to do so i have used php header as

```
header("location:Delivery_form.php?cnno=$cnno&copies='$nocopy'");
```

but it is redirecting in parent page. and javascript window.open as

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "window.open('Delivery_form.php?cnno='".$cnno."&copies=".$nocopy ")".
             "</script>";
```

please help me to achieve this funcnality.

Comment: Why not just create a link with `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php header should be :

```
header("location:Delivery_form.php?cnno=".$cnno."&copies=".$nocopy);
```

Script

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.open('Delivery_form.php?cnno=".$cnno."&copies=".$nocopy."', '_blank')
    </script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.open('Delivery_form.php?cnno=".$cnno."&copies=".$nocopy."', '_blank')
    </script>";
```